# sql update database not updating

Tags: php, input

I am trying to do a simple update query but for some reason its not working and i cannot figure out why not. Here is my code all on one file:

```
if(isset($_POST['order']))
        {
            $query = "update tienda set idp='$idp' where id=".$id;      
            $result = MYSQL_QUERY($query) or die(mysql_error());
        }

<td><? echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
                                                <td><input type=text name=idp class="inputorder" value="<? echo $row['idp']; ?>"</td>

        <input type=submit name=order value="." class="btn btn-primary">
```

The way it is at the moment it will display all the id and idp in the database on each row and the idp will be displayed as a input field. What i am trying to do is update database with the number that is in the idp field.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is your mysql server a localhost server?

Answer (score 1):

I solve all my problems with Neor Profiler for MySQL http://www.profilesql.com/
It's easy to use.
Just change your connection port in server var to connect in the 4040 port.
mysql_connect('localhost:4040', $user, $pass)
Then, open neor profiler and connect it to your MySQL server.
Your application will connect to neor profiler and it will bypass your queries showing all of them.
It's a powerfull tool. I can't to live without it.
Hope help.